# List of keyboard shortcuts for Terminal

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pantheon-terminal

Is there a list or is it possible to elaborate a full list of pantheon-terminal's shortcuts?

Example:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>L</kbd> Clears the screen
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>D</kbd> Closes active tab
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Opens new tab
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>1</kbd>...<kbd>9</kbd> Jumps to first-ninth tab

Answer (score 63, accepted):

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Open terminal

**Shortcuts Pantheon Terminal**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> Closes active tab
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> Closes tab
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Opens new tab
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>...<kbd>9</kbd> Jumps to first-ninth tab
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> Increase font size
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> Decrease font size
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> Copy selected text
  (if nothing is selected, it will terminate the current process)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> Paste clipboard text
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> Open new window
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Open search field
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> Select all text
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> Previous Tab
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> Next Tab

**Shortcuts Bash**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> Clears the screen
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> Terminate the command
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> Search command history backwards
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> go to the start of the command line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> go to the end of the command line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> cut from cursor to the end of the command line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> cut from cursor to the start of the command line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> cut from cursor to start of word
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> move backward one word (or go to start of word the cursor is currently on)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> move forward one word (or go to end of word the cursor is currently on)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> delete to end of word starting at cursor
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> capitalize to end of word starting at cursor
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> make uppercase from cursor to end of word
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> make lowercase from cursor to end of word
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> swap current word with previous
- `!!` run last command
- `!word` – run the most recent command that starts with ‘word’
- ... and various other shortcuts

Comment: !! sudo - the most useful command ever

Comment: Ctrl + _ (underscore) :  undo

Comment: Ctrl+k/u/w doesn't delete. they cut, you can then paste/yank with Ctrl+y

Answer (score 0):

Well, the above mentioned shortcuts are the standard ones you would find in most of the terminals. As a side node, I would like to say that you can actually customize these and set shortcuts you might prefer fr your system by tweaking the config file for your terminal or by using the GUI by chamging the preferences for your terminal.