# How can I make Ctrl+D not close the tab in Pantheon Terminal?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pantheon-terminal, bash

I've encountered something when using Pantheon Terminal. Normally, I expect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to delete the character at point if there is one, else if there aren't any characters on the line, send `EOF` (standard bash keyboard shortcut). However, it [looks like](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/981/list-of-keyboard-shortcuts-for-terminal) the standard keyboard shortcuts for `pantheon-terminal` include <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to directly close the current tab.

My shell is set to `/bin/bash`

```
> env | grep -i shell
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

and I've checked for options using `dconf-editor` under `org.pantheon.terminal.settings` and couldn't find anything to help create the behavior I expect.

How can I disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> closing the terminal tab so I that it behaves how I expect it to?

Comment: @LewisGoddard et al. Why was this closed? “Change the default behavior of Terminal” would be a feature request, but this question is asking how to change it in one user's settings, that's a how-to question, not a feature request.

Comment: @Gilles I have re-opened the question, and will leave it to the community to close it again. Asking for a workaround is no different to a feature request, except the lack of care about the source of the instruction. Plus, I don't think this is possible with the current code.

Comment: Thanks for re-opening this @Gilles, looks like someone was able to provide an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disable save-exited-tabs and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> can be used for bash. Just run:

`gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings save-exited-tabs false`

Comment: Thank you @Djax, worked like a charm. I also would have never come to the conclusion that this would've fixed it. Any idea if this will have any side affects I might not be aware of? If not, I think I'm set.

Comment: Not working for me. After executing that command, Ctrl+D still close my terminal. Very annoying.