# Pantheon-terminal key binds

Tags: pantheon-terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I've just recently moved from Fedora to Elementary, and this is just about the only thing I miss.

I want to set a keybind to cycle through tabs in the terminal window, I'm used to running vim in one tab and use the other tab to compile or run code. I'm so used to having this feature bound to  (left and right), and using the mouse to cycle between the tabs is just awkward and is to slow.

The solution I've found is to install gnome-terminal, but I really like the sleek looks of the built in one (pantheon) so I hope there is a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 8):

In the Pantheon Terminal you can move between terminal tabs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> respectively.

You might as well be interested in [List of keyboard shortcuts for Terminal](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/981/list-of-keyboard-shortcuts-for-terminal)

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way to change those keybind, as the supposed one crashes with my vim configuration (buffer cycling)

Comment: These are hard-coded so you cannot change them unless willing to compile your own version.

Answer (score 0):

If you set keyboard layout switch binding to "ctrl+shift" then terminal bindings stop to work;)

Comment: that's a bug then..