# Ctrl + Tab not working for Loki Terminal with Fish

Tags: pantheon-terminal, shell, fish

I am using the latest Elementary 0.4 with Fish as my primary shell; Ctrl + Tab used to switch between the shell tabs is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is no (more) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> hotkey, you can move with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1-9</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←/→</kbd>

Cf. [Pantheon-terminal key binds](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10045/pantheon-terminal-key-binds)