# How to change terminal shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pantheon-terminal

I use `irsii` in terminal, and I would like to use Alt-1, ..., Alt-9 to switch between irssi windows, but these keybindings are already taken from terminal to switch between terminal tabs.

I read [this useful answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/981/list-of-keyboard-shortcuts-for-terminal/983#983), and I explored the settings in `dconf-editor`, but I didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the answer of @"Alex Mitchell", I realized that the `alt_changes_tab` setting is responsible for the behavior I would like to modify, and I realized that this setting can be accessed and changed through dconf-editor, so I eventually solved my problem.

**Edit**
I mean, changed in the sense that the Alt+num keybindings can be completely disabled, not configured, but this is enough for me.

**Edit2**
To answer to the comment:

- install the package `dconf-editor`, I did it from command line

  ```
  sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
  ```
- launch the application, it is called *Editor dconf*,
- search for the string *terminal*, clicking on the search tool icon on the upper right part of the window
- click on */io/elementary/terminal*
- click on *settings*
- toggle the switch on the right of the setting on *alt-changes-tab*

Comment: Could you please outline how you change  the shortcuts?

Comment: @JamieHutber: done

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the terminal shortcuts are hardcoded. I'm not sure if there's plans to make them configurable. To solve your problem, I see two possible solutions:

1. Modify the source code and compile locally. I see some mention of alt keys here https://github.com/elementary/terminal/blob/master/src/PantheonTerminalWindow.vala#L410. It might be as simple as removing the cases `case Gdk.Key.@1:` to `case Gdk.Key.@9:` from the switch statement. There's also instructions on how to compile here https://github.com/elementary/terminal/
2. Use a different terminal emulator like `xterm` or `gnome-terminal`

Answer (score -1):

As you haven't specified which terminal you would like to use, the answer was simply:

`sudo apt install gnome-terminal`

From here you can set the shortcuts the through the normal preferences.